# Why my 2 custom view layouts are overlapping each others although I'm using LinearLayout

Tags: android

I try to add to custom views during runtime.

### MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.bug;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        android.view.ViewGroup root = (android.view.ViewGroup)getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        View v0 = this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_view, null);
        View v1 = this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_view, null);
        ((android.widget.TextView)v0.findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText("Text view 1");
        ((android.widget.TextView)v1.findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText("Text view 2");
        // I expect v1 will below v0 as we are using vertical LinearLayout.
        // However, they are overlapping each others.
        root.addView(v0);
        root.addView(v1);
    }
}
```

### custom_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >
    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

### activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>
```

However, I do not understand. I expect the 2nd view will on the bottom of 1st view. However, I'm getting overlapping result.

### (Do it through Java way)

[image]

Is there any steps I had done wrongly? Thank you.

Note, thing works fine if I add the 2 custom views through XML way instead of Java. But I still do not understand why my Java way doesn't work?

### activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <include layout="@layout/custom_view"/>
    <include layout="@layout/custom_view"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

### (Do it through XML way)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you aren't adding your `View`s to your `LinearLayout` in `activity_main.xml`, instead your are adding to the root `ViewGroup` which is not a `LinearLayout`. Reference your `LinearLayout` directly and add them to it, like this:

### activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/main_activity_linear_layout" >

</LinearLayout>
```

### MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_activity_linear_layout);
    View v0 = this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_view, null);
    View v1 = this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_view, null);
    ((android.widget.TextView)v0.findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText("Text view 1");
    ((android.widget.TextView)v1.findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText("Text view 2");

    // I expect v1 will below v0 as we are using vertical LinearLayout.
    // However, they are overlapping each others.
    root.addView(v0);
    root.addView(v1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you explicitly specify linear layout parameters (width and height) in your code when adding the views:

```
View v0 = this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_view, null);
View v1 = this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_view, null);
...

LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

root.addView(v0, lp);
root.addView(v1, lp);
```

Make sure that you're importing `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` and not `LayoutParams` from some other class.